# How to repaint a text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, repaint

I have a problem in my game, whitch im preety sure its concerning repaint. So this game is that if you touch the blue cube by manually controlling your black cube by the arrow keys you get a point each time. Well when you do that as it adds up, the new score draws on it self. This picture is a better explanation(Thankyou):

[image]

Here is the [JSFiddle Format](https://jsfiddle.net/abogal6274/k0mLauqo/2/embedded/result/) , Click on edit in the top right corner to edit the code. WARNING : you need to click on the game to work.

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Snake Game</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Basic styling, centering the canvas -->
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id = "game" width = "500" height = "500"></canvas>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
   var WIDTH = 500;
   var HEIGHT = 500;
   var keys = {};
   var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var score=0;

   var snake = {
      x:null,
      y:null,
      width:15,
      height:15,
      speed : 7,
      draw:function(){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.restore();

      },
 /*
left arrow  37
up arrow  38
right arrow 39
down arrow  40

  */
      update:function(){

        if(keys[39]){
          ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
          this.x += this.speed;
        }
        if(keys[37]){
          ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
          this.x -= this.speed;
        }
        if(keys[38]){
          ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
          this.y -= this.speed;
        }
        if(keys[40]){
          ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
          this.y += this.speed;
        }

        //Checks if it is out of Bounds
        if(this.x>WIDTH-this.width){
          this.x=WIDTH-this.width;

        }
        if(this.x<0){
          this.x=0;

        }
        if(this.y>HEIGHT-this.width){
          this.y=HEIGHT-this.width;
        }
        if(this.y<0){
          this.y=0;
        }

        //Checks Collision
         var Collision = function(ax, ay, aw, ah, bx, by, bw, bh) {
              return ax < bx+bw && ay < by+bh && bx < ax+aw && by < ay+ah;
                };

        if(Collision(snake.x,snake.y,snake.width,snake.height,fruits.x,fruits.y,fruits.width,fruits.height)){
          ctx.clearRect(fruits.x, fruits.y, fruits.width, fruits.height);
          score +=1;
          fruits.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*WIDTH);
          fruits.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*HEIGHT);
        }

      }
   }

   var fruits = {
      x:null,
      y:null,
      width:15,
      height:15,
      draw:function(){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.restore();
      },
      update:function(){

      }
   }

   function main(){

    document.addEventListener("keydown" , function(event){
                keys[event.keyCode] = true;
            })

  document.addEventListener("keyup" , function(event){
                delete keys[event.keyCode];
            })

    init();

     var loop = function (){
   update();
   draw();
      window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
    };
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
   }



   function init(){


    snake.x = 20;
    snake.y = 20;
    fruits.x = (WIDTH)/2;
    fruits.y = HEIGHT/2;

   }

   function draw(){

    //Drawing the Square
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(0,HEIGHT);
    ctx.lineTo(HEIGHT,WIDTH);
    ctx.lineTo(WIDTH,0)
    ctx.lineTo(0,0)
    ctx.stroke();

     ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.font = "bold 40px monaco";
    ctx.fillText(score,60,100);
    ctx.save();

    snake.draw();
    fruits.draw();

    ctx.restore();


   }

  function update(){
    snake.update();
    fruits.update();

  }



main();

   })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: .... Omg im really dum if this works..

Comment: You are already using `clearRect` in your code. So you should already know it clears a rectangle.

Comment: It dosent work. The text dosent work. When i clearRect() the score text it didnt work, i put this right before where i fill the style of the text: ctx.clearRect(60,100,100,100)

Comment: If i brush on it using my cube though it will be erased like a pencil eraser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
ctx.save();
ctx.clearRect(1, 1, WIDTH - 2, HEIGHT - 2);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.font = "bold 40px monaco";
ctx.fillText(score,60,100);
ctx.save();
```

It seems to work ok for me in your JSFiddle.  The rect is the whole screen so you reduce the size of it if you want.

Comment: It does work thanks! Can you please explain deeply how you did this? So i dont encounter this problem again? Thankyou

Comment: There is only 1 line to it, ctx.clearRect().  The parameters are (startX, startY, width, height).  I've used 1,1 and WIDTH-2 and HEIGHT-2 so I didn't clear the border but you could just as easily clear the whole thing and redraw the border.